# How can I make my own .remove() methode from an ObservableCollection in C#

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I made my own ObservableCollection with the help from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern this link. I can add animals in to a list with my own function .AddAnimal() but how could I remove a specific animal thats in my lists with .remove(). So if I have like the following animals in my list: dog, cat, fish, hamster. how could I get it so it removes: .remove(fish or "fish"). I'm able to remove it out of my `private List<Animal> animals;` but not out of `private List<IObserver<Animal>> observers;` this is my code so far, this is my observableInventory(observableCollection) where I have the add/remove() methodes

```
    namespace C_Advanced.Model
{
    internal class ObservableInventory : IObservable<Animal>
    {
        private List<IObserver<Animal>> observers;
        private List<Animal> animals;

        public ObservableInventory()
        {
            observers = new List<IObserver<Animal>>();
            animals = new List<Animal>();
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Animal> observer)
        {
            // Check whether observer is already registered. If not, add it
            if (!observers.Contains(observer))
            {
                observers.Add(observer);
            }
            return new Unsubscriber<Animal>(observers, observer);
        }

        public void AddAnimal(Animal animal)
        {
            animals.Add(animal);
            foreach(IObserver<Animal> observer in observers)
            {
                observer.OnNext(animal);
            }
        }
        public void RemoveAnimal(Animal animal)
        {
            //this part doesn't work
            animals.Remove(animal);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my inventoryObserver.cs:

```
    namespace C_Advanced.Model
{
    internal class InventoryObserver : IObserver<Animal>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnNext(Animal value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am {0} and this is the price of the animal: {1}",Name, value.Price);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my program.cs, here I want to be able to do .remove():

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double TotalWeight = 0;

        ObservableInventory inventory = new();
        InventoryObserver observer1 = new() { Name = "Seller1" };
        InventoryObserver observer2 = new() { Name = "Seller2" };
        inventory.Subscribe(observer1);
        inventory.Subscribe(observer2);

        inventory.AddAnimal(new Bird { Price = 10, Weight = 20 });
        inventory.AddAnimal(new Fish { Price = 2 });
        inventory.RemoveAnimal(new Fish { Name = "splash"});
    }
}
```

and here is my animal.cs:

```
    namespace C_Advanced.Model
{
    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }


        //internal Animal(double AnimalPrice, double AnimalWeight)
        //{
        //    this.Price = AnimalPrice;
        //    this.Weight = AnimalWeight;
        //}

        public virtual void MakeSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SOUND");
        }

        public virtual void MyType()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ANIMAL TYPE");
        }

        public double Prijs
        {
            get { return this.Price; }
        }

        public double From
        {
            get { return this.Weight; }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: But it is working in my test. The item is removed from  private List<Animal> animals; if it is the same instance that was added. What is not removed it is the Observer from List<IObserver<Animal>> observers of that animal.

Comment: @DA do u maybe have any idea on how to remove it from IObserver<Animal> aswell. because u cant do .remove(animal) on that

Comment: What is `inventory.RemoveAnimal()` with no Animal parameter supposed to do? How did that code even compile?

Comment: Same for `animals.Remove()`, shouldn't it be `animals.Remove(animal)`?

Comment: @HasaniH Not, that doesn't work like that, only if i do "inventory.RemoveAnimal(new Fish { Name = "splash"})" but like DA said I need to empty the IObserver list and not the private animal list

Comment: @HasaniH ur correct. I was just testing some things out and it seems like I forgot to put that back. I have updated the code now tho

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment about `inventory.RemoveAnimal(new Fish { Name = "splash"})` being the issue, I think your problem is with equality checking.

```
var fish1 = new Fish { Name = "splash"};
ObservableInventory animals = new();
animals.AddAnimal(fish1);
// the line below does not remove fish1 from the collection
animals.RemoveAnimal(new Fish { Name = "splash"});
```

You have not overidden the `Equals` method or provided an `IEqualityComparer` so that `Animal`s with the same `Name` are considered equal. If that's the behavior you want you'll need to implement it otherwise `Remove` will use reference equality i.e.

```
// to remove fish1
animals.RemoveAnimal(fish1);
```

Comment: But there is no animals in my program.cs. So how could I do animals.RemoveAnimal(fish1)?